# Java doc comment not showing fully

Tags: java, javadoc

So this is a snippet from one of my classes with a java doc comment btu when i call it the java doc doesnt show fully only the first param shows the rest is not present why? what am i doing wrong? Do i need to format it properly?

```
/**
     * @param String timestamp
     * @param int empire
     * @param int federation
     * @param int independent
     * @param int alliance
     */
    public ReputationEvent(String timestamp, int empire, int federation, int independent, int alliance) {
        super(timestamp);
        this.empire = empire;
        this.federation = federation;
        this.independent = independent;
        this.alliance = alliance;
    }
```

[Calling Class to create new instance of it, not showing the full java doc comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLmzG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order of your @param. Usually you don't write the type of the variable.

```
/**
 * <A short description of your method / class / whatever>
 *
 * @param <name of the variable> <describe your variable>
 */
```

Example:

```
/**
 * Print a number on the screen.
 *
 * @param number The number that will be print on the screen.
 */
```

[Source](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Comment: yes that worked I mixed up the order of variable name and description, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
@param <name of parameter> <description>
```

If you generate javadoc from your example, it gives you the following error:

> error: @param name not found* @param int federation

Because "int" is not the expected name for the parameter, which is "federation".